# Splitting strings in python, then joining them into so that each string is one substring longer than the next

Tags: python, string, split

Basically what I want to do is take a string like this:

```
-o-pp-gg-s-h
```

then turn it into the series of strings:

```
-o
-o-pp
-o-pp-gg
-o-pp-gg-s
-o-pp-gg-s-h
```

I know that I could do this by splitting the string (`str.split('-')`), then having a loop that joins the substrings to produce that output (`'-'.join(lst)`). However, is there a more elegant way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehension!

```
s = "-o-pp-gg-s-h"
ss = s.split("-")
series = ["-".join(ss[:x]) for x in range(2,len(ss)+1)]
```

Is this elegant enough?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s='-o-pp-gg-s-h'
>>> nlist=s.split('-')
>>> for i in range(len(nlist)):
...  print '-'.join(nlist[:i])
... 


-o
-o-pp
-o-pp-gg
-o-pp-gg-s
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a
'-o-pp-gg-s-h'
>>> b=a.split('-')

>>> b
['', 'o', 'pp', 'gg', 's', 'h']
>>> for i in range(len(b)+1):
...     print '-'.join(b[0:i])


-o
-o-pp
-o-pp-gg
-o-pp-gg-s
-o-pp-gg-s-h
```

Answer (score 1):

Only for variety, using `accumulate` (in modern Python):

```
In [23]: s = '-o-pp-gg-s-h'

In [24]: from itertools import accumulate

In [25]: list(accumulate(s.split('-'), lambda x,y: x+'-'+y))[1:]
Out[25]: ['-o', '-o-pp', '-o-pp-gg', '-o-pp-gg-s', '-o-pp-gg-s-h']
```